# Ribbon XML Supertip hyperlink

Tags: xml, hyperlink, tooltip, ribbon

How do you render a click-able hyperlink into a supertip in Ribbon XML?

I've seen this done in various applications, but can't seem to find any guidance on how to do it (everything I find seems to instead be advising to add a ribbon button that is coded to follow a link).

[image: MS Word supertip "tell me more" link example.]

I don't need to retrieve or form a dynamic link in code, I just need to do this as a static string that won't change at run-time.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: I still haven't managed to find anything on this. Anybody have any help / pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.aspx) (this is for `RibbonButton`, but others are the same) doesn't say anything about it, and there is nothing in parent classes either.

Also see [this link about fixing the `Tell Me More` link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67c50a69-2f92-43ba-8c66-160a087aa7b7/fix-the-tell-me-more-link-on-supertips?forum=vsto). That area of the supertip is not intended to be modified by Add-Ins, despite how useless the links it provides are.

Wherever you saw this done, it wasn't in VSTO.

Comment: My own research had been leading me to that conclusion also.  So annoying that this isn't possible, but thanks for the conclusive answer anyhow. :)